# A network related or instance specific error on Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting error whenever I connect to the instance(DESKTOP-0LFC1LP) on Sql Server. I'm using Sql server 2012.

I don't know what's the reason but whenever I install Sql server , It works perfectly for a day or two and after that it starts giving me this error.
I can solve this by re-installing Sql and it will work fine but again only for a day. I want a permanent solution to this. And please also tell why it works after I reinstall it?

Your help would be appreciated!

Error says:

> ### TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to DESKTOP-0LFC1LP.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)
>
> ---
>
> The system cannot find the file specified
>
> ---

---

Comment: please Check is the sql server services is running on the DESKTOP-0LFC1LP? then check SQL Server config manager for the TCP/IP protocol enable?

Comment: Can you please provide steps to do this?

Comment: that could be happening for the following reason:

service stopped?
firewall restriction?
default port changed?

SQL Server folder/ Configuration Tools / Configuration Manager

you can take a look at this path and confirm the scenarios the most common one it's service stopped or remote server not working etc